# How to control which iESS process gets a code evaluation?

Tags: ess, r

I have several R instances running and want to pick which one gets the evaluations in my buffer. Is there a built-in way of doing this?

Comment: If you have an R script open and more than one running R process, you should be prompted to pick which process to associate with your script file when you evaluate anything from that buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> is bound to `ess-switch-process`. You can also start a new process this way.